# Disable minification in docusaurus?

Tags: docusaurus

I see [the flag](https://docusaurus.io/docs/cli#docusaurus-build-sitedir) to disable minification for Docusaurus, but the flag only appears to work for `docusaurus build` and not for `docusaurus start`. Is there a way to do something equivalent when running locally? It would make browser debugging *much* easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the feature in [this PR](https://github.com/facebook/docusaurus/pull/7452)